# Qt GUI looks different on Linux, Mac, and Windows

Tags: qt

When I am creating a UI application using Qt, I saw that when I am running on Mac, Windows, and Linux the UI are different, especially the space between widgets (button, checkbox, etc) and also the margin on text inside the widgets.
On my Mac the space between widget are way too big I think, so UI look are very bad on Mac. Is there anything I can do to make it better?
But when I saw QtCreator on Linux, Windows, and Mac, they looks the same. What is the technique used by QtCretor UI?

Sorry I can not share the looks of my app here, due to my contract.

Comment: But you could share the looks of a dummy app, so that we can have further evidence

Comment: Ah true, OK i will make a dummy GUI just for shown.

Comment: Use a "Fusion" type of `QStyle`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enforce the same look, you can set the style when you start your application through [QApplication::setStyle()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle). Then it should look the same on all platforms. You probably loose the native look, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, its look better for now.

Comment: Btw: this solution also has another advantage: Think a user changed the default style to a buggy one (e.g. downloaded from the internet). Then your application would also be buggy due to using this style, and you would get bug reports even though it's not your fault. Therefore, setting a style makes lots of sense from a company's perspective.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use **qtconfig** command to setup Look And Feel